# angular 2 typescript moment install not working

Tags: angular, momentjs, systemjs, npm-install

I am trying to install moment.

After `npm install moment --save`, I import moment in my component, but when reload the page, I got 404 error: http://localhost:3000/moment

here is my component file import code:

```
import {Input, Output, Component} from "angular2/core"
import {TicketService} from "../services/ticket.service"
import {Ticket} from "./ticket";
import {OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {Router, RouteParams, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

I don't understand why. Could someone help me on that ?

### Here is my System.config

```
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Try to install angular2-moment package.

Comment: Did you define your 'map' to be mapped under node_modules?

Comment: @echonax no, I didn't

Comment: Can you share your system.config.js?

Comment: @echonax hi, I added, thanks~

Comment: it is working for me; verify that is added to your *package.json*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map that 'moment' path to something under your system config. So it will know where to go.

```
 System.config({
        map:{
           'moment':                  './node_modules/moment/moment'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
```

The exact path may vary depending on your architecture of course.

Comment: then it's Cannot GET /node_modules/moment/moment

Comment: checked it's added in the dependencies

Comment: I just wrote the path as an example. I don't know where your moment main file is. You must change it accordingly